# Import a word document for editing either with ckedit or.. something else?

Tags: ms-word

Is there a way to accurately import a word doc so that it can be edited with ckeditor?
currently, ckeditor allows copy paste from word, but the formatting isnt't exact.

So I was wondering if maybe there was some tool out there that we could use to maybe accurately convert the word doc to html to use is ckeditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this using docx4j.  If working in java on the server is an option for you, I'd be happy to forward you my code.

Comment: Hi Jason, I posed a question similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490529/docx4j-conversion-html-docx-html  I was wondering if you could take a look and perhaps link to the code you implemented?  Thank you!

Comment: Update 2018: If you want to avoid issues associated with converting to/from (X)HTML, you might like to try https://www.nativedocuments.com/ (disclosure: I have an interest here).  Native Documents focuses on providing fidelity comparable to Word itself, whilst being easy for developers to embed in a webapp.